# c# easiest way to extract substring

Tags: c#

i have a string:

```
string somestring = "\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15939-E.ESY"
```

i need to extract `15939`

it will always be a 5 digit number, always preceeded by '\' and it will always "-" after it

Comment: Are there ever `-` characters elsewhere in the string?

Comment: Will it always be after the last '\'?

Comment: @joel yes there might be

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: RegExp seems like too much overhead for this.

Comment: "easy" and "well defined" counteract one another.  Which do you want?

Comment: I think Brad's answer got both Brian :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
String result = Path.GetFileName("\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15939-E.ESY").Split('-')[0];
```

Perhaps?

Comment: +1 for using `Path.GetFileName` instead of trying to regex all the way there.

Comment: Hah I had a more convoluted answer with substring and split's. Good job recognizing it was a path.

Comment: +1: That is a nice solution. I wouldn't have initially thought to treat it as a file.

Comment: UNC paths; I've been dealing with them for the last several weeks, heh. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This regex does the trick for the input string you provided:

```
        var input = "\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15939-E.ESY";

        var pattern = @".*\\(\d{5})-";

        var result = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
```

But I actually like Brad's solution using Path.GetFileName more :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try (based on your answer in the comments about the `\` character):

```
string result = myString.SubString(myString.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1, 5);
```